# JS XMLHttpRequest wrong result

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i have begin learning JavaScript from w3schools and i've stucked on sending GET request - i get wrong status code (0) and no content.
maybe my code in mvc is wrong:

```
  [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Insider.Dto.CustomerDto),200)]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            var response = service.GetCustomers();
            var result = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = result,
            };

        }
```

It works, when i debug it in VS i get right dto's, but when i try to display it by js, i get only '0' (its status code), other properties are null

```
<script>
    function GetData()
    {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText + this.status + this.responseXML
     var response = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:3784/api/customers", true);
  xhttp.send();
    }
</script>

<button onclick="GetData()">Get data</button>
<p id="demo">data...</p>
```

i susspose that something is wrong with returning result on my mvc application, but what am i doing wrong :( ?

Comment: any cors errors in the developer tools console?

Comment: emmm sorry, i have this : "ReferenceError: xhttp is not defined
    at eval (eval at GetData.xhttp.onreadystatechange (file:///C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/angular/api_communication.html:8:26), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.GetData.xhttp.onreadystatechange (file:///C:/Users/Adam/Desktop/angular/api_communication.html:8:26)"

Comment: First, don't use `this`. Or read about it, because it is quite special in JS and the `this` value can be something you don't expect. Second, `new XMLHttpRequest()` is quite oldschool: use a library or use `fetch` in the most recent browsers! ;)

Comment: To check if the error is serverside have a look at the request in the network tab of F12 tools

Comment: ok, can you show me some example? maybe its weird, but i try to dont watch other JS courses before i finish on w3schools.

Comment: oh, you're trying to access a http resource from a file loaded using `file:///` protocol - yes, that wont work usually

Comment: @sjahan - his use of `this` is perfectly ok where he is using it! as far a XHR being old school? that's complete rubbish, most "libraries" will use XHR - fetch being "too new" (because of internet explorer) to rely on - besides, fetch has limitations not present in XHR

Comment: @JaromandaX: I didn't accurately check the `this` usage, just giving the advice to be careful with it because this is a classic bug for JS newbies, or at least, read about it. About XHR, i agree every library relies on it, what i meant is: use these libraries. XHR is quite low-level and using any framework/library above it will give better results in my opinion. I haven't used directly XHR for years, always using jQuery or Angular or anything, that's what it feels quite old-school to me.

Answer (score 0):

it's me again.
problem was with CORS
i have added by NugetPackage CORS, next i have updated webconfig (xml) file

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

and now its working, i can call my api from C:\something\file and from localhost/somefile.html (when hosting on iis)